# How do I get the opposite results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

new to the scene of web developing/design

I've been trying to do this for a week now, but can't seem to figure it out so I was hoping I can get some help, it's basically a light switch

So what I'm trying to do is, when I click the switch the background changes colour, text and image changes as well and vice versa.

Umm here's my attempt, I can get it to change background colour and switch the image, but the text doesn't seem to be changing and I when I re-click it's not changing back to the original state

Here are the images:
http://oi59.tinypic.com/96xhec.jpg
http://oi62.tinypic.com/350ug5l.jpg

html:

```
<img class="swoff" src="img/switch_off.png">

<span class="msg">Hey, who turn off the lights?</span>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"><\/script>')    </script>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-size:1em;
text-align:center;
margin-top:31%;
background:#151515;
}

.swoff {
display:block;
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
width:200px;
height:200px;
}

.msg {
color:#fff;
}

.lighttxt {
color:#3c3c3c;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('.swoff').on('click', function() {

var dark = "Hey, who turn off the lights?";
var light = "It's so bright in here!";
var swon = "img/switch_on.png";

if($('img').attr('src',swon)) {

    $('body').css({'background-color':'#FFFFF2'});
    $('msg').html(dark);

}
else {

    $('img').attr(swon,'src')
    $('body').css({'background-color':'#151515'});
    $('msg').html(light);
}
```

Comment: You should create a jsfiddle. Makes solving the problem much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's easier to work with CSS classes and use the [available jQuery methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/) (`addClass`,`removeClass`, etc).

In jQuery, inside element events, the shortcut `$(this)` refers to the element itself:

```
$('element').on('click', function(){ $(this).something(); });
```

Also, use `#` to target the ID of elements (`#id`) and `.` to target the class (`.class`), we omit this only for HTML tags (`input`, `img`, `form`, etc).

---

**Runnable snippet:**

```js
$('#switch').on('click', function() {

    var dark = "Hey, who turn off the lights?";
    var light = "It's so bright in here!";
  
    if( $(this).hasClass('swoff') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('swoff').addClass('swon');
     $('body').css({'background-color':'#FFFFF2'});
     $('#msg').html(light).removeClass('darktext').addClass('lighttxt');
    }
    else {
        $(this).removeClass('swon').addClass('swoff');
        $('body').css({'background-color':'#151515'});
        $('#msg').html(dark).removeClass('lighttxt').addClass('darktext');
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size:1em;
  text-align:center;
  background:#151515;
}
#switch {
  display:block;
  margin: auto;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
.swoff {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7Clv.png');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.swon {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbKrW.png');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.darktxt {
  color:#fff;
}
.lighttxt {
  color:#3c3c3c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="switch" class="swoff"></div>

<span id="msg" class="darktxt">Hey, who turn off the lights?</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you had in mind with this line:

```
if($('img').attr('src',swon)) {
```

If you are trying to say "is the src attribute on the image the same as swon", then you want this:

```
if($('img').attr('src')==swon) {
```

Calling attr with one argument (i.e. `.attr('src')` ) gets the attribute, calling it with two (i.e. `.attr('src',swon)` ), sets it.  So instead of checking if the src is equal to swon, you are instead setting it each time.  This is the first reason it wasn't toggling.  Your other line `$('img').attr(swon,'src')` is also whacky (wrong argument sequence).

There's more to fix but hopefully that helps.

NOTE: You're missing "});" at the end of the JS.